# What does the following PHP function serve as?

Tags: php

```
function query($conn, $query) {
$rows = [];

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
 }
return $rows;
}
```

Im having problem to understand this.
Please help

Comment: fetching data from database. `$query` will contain your query.

Comment: How difficult is it to [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)?

Comment: `function` = an object that stored a procedure inside of it. `($params)` = something that is passed into the function that can be used inside its **scope**. `$conn` represents a **database** connection and your `$query` holds your **SQL**. `return` = send this back to the calling variable: ie - `$toMe = query(mysqli_connect(...., "select * from ....");`

Comment: Thanks a lot Kyle E4K

Answer (score 0):

This function helps to get data from database,  `$conn` parameter is a connection to database, `$query` is an sql statement like `SELECT * FROM country`. function will fetch data from database and return array of results.

Comment: Thanks a lot LightNight.

Answer (score 0):

This function would connect to database and get rows.

This line will connect and query the database:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

This line will get rows when the query succeeded:

```
if($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
 }
```

More information on `mysqli_fetch_array` at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp.

This line will return the array `$rows`:

```
return $rows;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot luweiqi, I really appreciate ur help.